# Passing values from forms elements to input boxes

Tags: jquery

I have some form elements (checkbox, radio, input, select,...) and I would like to pass the actual and the selected value from a field to another. Now I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/fsogvrdm/

```
$(function() {
    $("#NameFrom").keyup(function() {
        $('#NameTo').val(this.value);
    });
    $("input[name='GenderFrom']").change(function() {
        $('#GenderTo').val(this.value);
    });
    $("#CheckboxFrom").change(function() {
       $('#CheckboxTo').val(this.checked);
    });
    $("input[name='DateFrom']").change(function() {
        $('#DateTo').val(this.value);
    });
    $("#SelectboxFrom").change(function() {
        $('#SelectboxTo').val(this.value);
    });    
});
```

This works for every field, besides the **Date** and for the **Select to pass multiple values**.

Is it possible to pass the values from Date and Select?

Comment: If you are using JQuery I would suggest you *get* the values with `$(this).val()` instead. This might fix your data issue, not sure how it will turn out with multi-select box though... try it

Comment: Actually, your date input doesn't have a *name* so that is a probably for starts. Also it is a `div` not an `input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this to add date and values : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/7sjqebb4/)

the library documentation have the event for datepicker `change.bfhdatepicker` [bootstrapformhelpers.com/datepicker](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/datepicker/)

```
$(function() {
    $("#NameFrom").keyup(function() {
        $('#NameTo').val(this.value);
    });
    $("input[name='GenderFrom']").change(function() {
        $('#GenderTo').val(this.value);
    });
    $("#CheckboxFrom").change(function() {
       $('#CheckboxTo').val(this.checked);
        alert('ff');
    });
    $("input[name='DateFrom']").change(function() {
        $('#DateTo').val(this.value);
    });
    $("#SelectboxFrom").change(function() {
        f2();
    }); 
    $('.bfh-datepicker').on('change.bfhdatepicker',function(){
        f1();
    });

    var f1=function(){
      $('#DateTo').val($('[name=DateFrom]').val());
    }
    var f2=function(){
      $('#SelectboxTo').val($("#SelectboxFrom").val());
    }
    //launch initials
    f1();
    f2();
});
```

Comment: miglio, thanks. But how can I populate the input *To with the acual values from the *From elements? I mean... I could set the `value` fixed, but I would like to do get the default with JQuery.

Comment: you  want to fill all inputs?.  [http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/7sjqebb4/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/7sjqebb4/8/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack but should do the job.

```
 $(".bfh-datepicker-calendar").on("click",function() {
     setTimeout(function()
                {$('#DateTo').val($("input[name='DateFrom']").val());
     },0);
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fsogvrdm/1/